# WebStorm: Reformat code remove trailing ; at the end of the inline style

Tags: html, vue.js, webstorm

I have the following code in a `.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div style="background: red;"></div>
<template/>
```

When I reformat the code, it becomes:

```
<template>
  <div style="background: red"></div>
<template/>
```

It removes the `;`. I went through all the IDE settings, but didn't manage to turn it off.

Comment: Maybe there's a rule specified in your eslint file?

Comment: It's not really needed here hence why it is removed. It keeps it if you put 2 statements back to back tho.

Comment: My stylint forces me to have a semicolon at the end of any css properties. There isn't any option to turn it off for inline css.